# Unity 2D play animation with flipX then enabling and disabling GameObject "locks" flipX

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, sprites

I have a GameObject with an Animator that contains many different animations. In C# I switch between these animations with `animator.Play("AnimName")`. Some of the animations have the flipX property checked, so I can use the same sprite for two different directions.

This works well, but I have one animation where after it is done I call `gameObject.SetEnabled (false)` then re-enable it a short while later. I achieve this through an event at the end of the animation which calls a method in my script.

For some reason, if the last animation I played before disabling the object had the flipX property checked, then all the other sprite animations will be flipped after it is reenabled. I can fix this by adding the flipX property to the other animations then unchecking it, but I don't want to have to go through all my animations to add an unchecked property.

This seems like a bug to me, but if it's not, is there some way I can change the behavior?

Comment: To get around this I added `spriteRenderer.flipX = false;` just before calling `gameObject.SetEnabled(false);`. I feel like this shouldn't happen, but at least this is an easy way to get around it.